KVM/QEMU issues with TAP and static IP addresses
I'm trying to run OSv unikernels on KVM/Qemu. The networking side is handled by a piece of Golang software that generates TAP devices for VMs and assigns the VMs a static IP (not the TAPs!); the IP is passed as an OSv commandline parameter. The most basic setup looks like this:
Overview of interfaces
56: pod1313: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 46:0c:3b:50:7a:f2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.184.66.16/30 brd 10.184.66.19 scope global pod1313
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::440c:3bff:fe50:7af2/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
57: vetheafa@if58: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master pod1313 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether da:28:82:3e:29:a0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netns vmtest-debug
    inet6 fe80::d828:82ff:fe3e:29a0/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
59: vtapdf56: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 xdp/id:185 qdisc pfifo_fast master pod1313 state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 06:d1:4d:76:18:52 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

Where pod1313 acts as a bridge with IP 10.184.66.16, and vtapdf56 has a running VM attached with an internal static IP 10.184.66.18. The VM itself is started with:
QEMU start cmd
Setting cmdline: --rootfs=zfs --verbose --ip=eth0,192.168.122.2,255.255.255.0 --defaultgw=192.168.122.1 /main
Invoking QEMU at: /usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64 with arguments:
  -vnc unix:/root/.capstan/instances/qemu/vmtest_debug_app/vnc-domain-socket
  -m 1024
  -smp 1
  -device virtio-blk-pci,id=blk0,bootindex=0,drive=hd0
  -drive file=/root/.capstan/instances/qemu/vmtest_debug_app/disk.qcow2,if=none,id=hd0,aio=threads,cache=none
  -chardev stdio,mux=on,id=stdio,signal=off
  -device isa-serial,chardev=stdio
  -netdev bridge,id=hn0,br=virbr0,helper=/usr/lib/qemu/qemu-bridge-helper
  -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=hn0,id=nic1,mac=ea:28:4b:8e:91:eb
  -chardev socket,id=charmonitor,path=/root/.capstan/instances/qemu/vmtest_debug_app/osv.monitor,server=on,wait=off
  -mon chardev=charmonitor,id=monitor,mode=control
  -enable-kvm
  -cpu host,+x2apic
  -object memory-backend-file,id=mem,size=1024M,mem-path=/dev/shm,share=on
  -numa node,memdev=mem

Here's where the fun starts. When I try to ping the VM, it gets ARP requests because the bridge can't figure out where it is, and the ARP reply gets back to vtapdf56, but not all the way to pod1313 (the bridge):
ARP in vtapdf56
26  10.239985480    46:0c:3b:50:7a:f2   Broadcast   ARP 42  Who has 10.184.66.18? Tell 10.184.66.16
27  10.240199373    4b:b6:0c:c0:be:2b   46:0c:3b:50:7a:f2   ARP 42  10.184.66.18 is at 4b:b6:0c:c0:be:2b
28  11.264028353    46:0c:3b:50:7a:f2   Broadcast   ARP 42  Who has 10.184.66.18? Tell 10.184.66.16
29  11.264453585    4b:b6:0c:c0:be:2b   46:0c:3b:50:7a:f2   ARP 42  10.184.66.18 is at 4b:b6:0c:c0:be:2b

ARP in pod1313
3   2.048188015 46:0c:3b:50:7a:f2   Broadcast   ARP 42  Who has 10.184.66.18? Tell 10.184.66.16
4   3.071988103 46:0c:3b:50:7a:f2   Broadcast   ARP 42  Who has 10.184.66.18? Tell 10.184.66.16

This seems to be the main problem, but if I fix the ARP entry manually it's still not OK, since ping requests make it to the VM (supposedly), but nothing comes back out:
Ping but not pong
The problem here is that I can't actually get into the unikernel to check what's happening on that side. But that's not the issue because it actually did work at some point. It took a long time of trial and error, and I have no clue what fixed it in the first place, but there is an example:
Actual responses from when it worked
Don't mind the impressive message duplication, it's supposed to happen because that screenshot measures end-to-end, not just pod1313 to vtapdf56. After a forced reboot (thanks, electric company) whatever fixed it was reset and now it's back to this situation. I've tried everything from completely clearing iptables, accepting all traffic, disabling rp_filter, arp_filter, enabling arp_proxy, etc.. the lot.
The really annoying thing is that this even happens when I take all my software out of the equation and start a VM with a static IP attached to the default virbr0 with qemu-bridge-helper, so it's not even an issue with a buggy TAP setup on my part. There must be something really stupidly simple I'm overlooking, but at this point I have no idea what it could be.
My main question is: which settings or rules would I need to fix to have ARP work as expected (VM mac ends up in table) and be able to ping the VM (not just request, but also response)?
EDIT: interestingly, my trial-and-error resulted in a container on the same bridge getting hold of the VM MAC address and responding to the ARP request by proxy. However, instead of accepting that response, the bridge then started to use that container's MAC address as the VM's. It simply refuses to accept the VM's MAC address from any source.

Please consider posting most of these screenshots as text instead. Text will be easier to focus on what you believe is relevant, will be searchable, and will allow us to recreate your issues.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Added a few images as text; I'll add the rest asap but the setup isn't very cooperative in recreating those.

All of the sysctls you mentioned have to do with the OS accepting the responses – not with receiving them; what shows up on a packet capture is generally unaffected by filtering that happens later... But on the other hand I'm curious whether there are any ebtables rules that filter at the bridge level, as libvirt likes to add some. Other than that, does bridge fdb show the correct MAC table?

Well the fact that it worked before with no code changes indicates the OS messing with me yes. ebtables is empty (also checked before, but still empty):
Bridge table: filter
Bridge chain: INPUT, entries: 0, policy: ACCEPT
Bridge chain: FORWARD, entries: 0, policy: ACCEPT
Bridge chain: OUTPUT, entries: 0, policy: ACCEPT

As for bridge fdb, it doesn't have the VM MAC, but other devices are listed correctly (including the container also attached to it after pinging that), but it's too long to post.

Something to do with this? (I can't even set the MAC address of any of my interface to one that starts with 4b on my Linux systems: RTNETLINK answers: Cannot assign requested address.

Oh my, how embarrassing. I had actually checked the piece of code that generates those, but only for local and not multicast. Of course, I reused those for manual tests rather than making my own too. Please make an answer so I can select it as solved.

Apparently the Linux kernel prohibited the frames from going further / entering the bridge because the MAC address is invalid, as in, with the first octet being e.g. 4b, the multicast bit (i.e., the least significant bit of the first octet) would be set (1).

Btw, although it is irrelevant and probably not as bad, 10.184.66.16/30 is sort of invalid too, because 10.184.66.16 would be the subnet ID when it is /30.

Well spotted, and I definitely wouldn't recommend how I did that for any other situation. In this case it doesn't matter as much since the entire topology up to the veth pairs/TAP devs is "managed" by eBPF programs that technically violate much more than just that. But thanks a lot for the answer! Spent more than a day on this.
